# How do I move a Landscape image up towards the binding edge?

Tags: graphics, landscape

Please can you help me move this image up (towards the red line shown), without changing the margin size? raisebox did not seem to work...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=25cm]{c:/temp/Final_images/va_blacked.png}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could try, just after `\begin{figure}` adding a line `\vspace*{-<dimen>}`, where the dimension is however much the figure needs to be moved up.  it's a "bigger hammer" hack, but might be effective.

Answer (score 1):

this is most certainly a hack, but there has been confirmation in a comment
that it works.

the idea is to make latex think that the figure is smaller than it really is.
this can be accomplished by applying some negative vertical space at the top.

just after `\begin{figure}` add the line

```
\vspace*{-<dimen>}
```

where the dimension is however much the figure needs to be moved up.
the `*` is necessary, otherwise the `\vspace` will disappear at the top of
the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit manual, but you can change the size entering the calculations by adding a trim argument to `includegraphics`:

`\includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 74, width=25cm]{black320x200.png}`